# John-the-ripper, special chars and capitals

Tags: john-the-ripper

How can I use special characters and capitals using john.  this is what ive added to the conf file

```
[Incremental:All]
File = $JOHN/ascii.chr
MinLen = 8
MaxLen = 13 
CharCount = 105
Extra = !@#$%^&*()
[List.Extra]
CHARS = "!@#$%^&*()"
```

when running john it only uses lowercase and numbers, how can i get it to use the special chars and capitals?

Comment: What command are you running?